# In qml, how to display busyIndicator when dialog is accepted in filedialog?

Tags: qml

I want to display a busyindicator when the application is handling the task after filename is accepted by user in FileDialog, but appear that the main thread was blocked by filedialog. So the busyindicator can't be displayed. How can I solve it? Thanks

Code is below:

```html
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("E&xit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        button1.onClicked: {
            exportXlsxDialog.open()
        }
        FileDialog {
            id: exportXlsxDialog
            title: qsTr("Please choose a xslx file")
            nameFilters: [ "Excel 2007-2013 (*.xlsx)" ]
            selectExisting: false
            onAccepted: {
                busyIndicator.running = true
                sleep(10000)
                console.log(fileUrl)
                busyIndicator.running = false
            }
            function sleep(milliseconds) {
                var start = new Date().getTime();
                for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
                    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        BusyIndicator {
            id: busyIndicator
            z: 99
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            running: false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `sleep()` function doesn't give the `BusyIndicator` a chance to be shown, probably because it doesn't let Qt's event loop spin.

The best solution is probably to use a [WorkerScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-workerscript.html), but if you're lazy, you can use this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Timer {
        id: expensiveOperationDelay
        interval: 1
        onTriggered: sleep(2000)
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                break;
            }
        }
        busyIndicator.running = false
    }

    Button {
        text: "Click"
        onClicked: {
            busyIndicator.running = true
            expensiveOperationDelay.start()
//            sleep(2000)
        }
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        id: busyIndicator
        z: 99
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        running: false
    }
}
```

I simplified your example a bit, because the dialog isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem.

This pushes the responsibility of starting the expensive operation to a `Timer`. I gave it the smallest possible interval that resulted in events being processed (I thought that an interval of `0` would cause that, but apparently not), so that the indicator would be shown. I also had to move the hiding of the indicator to the end of the `sleep()` function, because if I had left it where it was, it would have been hidden again before it had ever been rendered.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I have tried workerscript, but it does not work. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere. I'll try it myself.